# Django 1.8 - how can staticfiles magically guess the hashed file name

Tags: django, amazon-s3

I'm storing my static files on Amazon S3 and I'm using Django's cache-busting, my storage class look like this:

```
class MyStaticFilesStorage(ManifestFilesMixin, S3BotoStorage):
    ...
```

See:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/contrib/staticfiles/#manifeststaticfilesstorage

After running  `manage.py collectstatic` all the static files are uploaded to S3 with the cache-busting hash in the file name.

Everything works great but I can't understand how.

- my `static` folder is in `.gitignore` so static files never reach my server.
- the `staticfiles.json` that django creates is stored on S3 only, so I went there and deleted it (so I can see if it has any effect).
- I can ssh to the server and verify that there's no file called `staticfiles.json` and non of the static files are on the server.

But with all that Django still generates on the server the correct static URL with the correct hash (for example: main.c076b26cc1a7.css).

How? How does django know the hash without the mapping (staticfiles.json) and without the original file?

Answer (score 1):

I´m guessing that Django first gets the **staticfiles.json** file from the S3 and then reads the mapping from the file.

Even thou your static folder is in **.gitignore**, when you run the `manage.py collectstatic`, you are telling Django to look in the static folder, so it know it has to get them from there. Don´t forget you don´t upload the contents in the static folder using `git pull`,you do it using `manage.py collectsatic`.